# Excluding a chapter from TOC

Tags: latex, pdflatex

In my LaTeX document I've got a table of contents that is automatically generated by collecting everything that is of the form `\chapter`.

However, I've got an acknowledgements chapter before the table of contents and I don't want it to be automatically labelled "Chapter 1" or captured in the table of contents. Should I be avoiding `\chapter` altogether and use `\section` instead? I want to keep the font/formatting that other chapters have though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The usual way to handle that kind of thing is with the `\frontmatter` command. Put it after the `\begin{document}`, and then put `\mainmatter` right before the `\chapter` you want to correspond to chapter 1. This may only work in the `book` class. If you're using `\chapter` in a `report`, then `\chapter*` should also create a chapter that has no number and won't show up in the table of contents.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, as unknown (google) mentioned, using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` is the best solution. This will also adjust your page numbering to lowercase roman numerals for the front matter. However, it works only on `book` and similar document classes.

In case you're using `report`, try `\chapter*`. This will create a chapter without a number that does not appear in the table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

For articles `\chapter*` does not appear to work. Instead use `\section*`.